# how to change an array to combine values belonging to same property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array in typescript with following structure

```
[{Zone: "4", Org: 1},
{Zone: "2", Org: 1},
{Zone: "4", Mem: 32},
{Zone: "2", Mem: 22}]
```

I want to change this to following,

```
[{Zone: "4", Org: 1, Mem: 32},
{Zone: "2", Org: 1, Mem: 22}],
```

I tried to create first a new set of zones as there will be more values in future, and then run a foreach on the set followed by a reduce function. But I am not sure if my approach is right. I am bit lost in how to move forward with this situation.

how can I achieve this in least possible code?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I tried to create first a new set of zones as there will be more values in future, and then run a foreach on the set followed by a reduce function. But I am not sure if my approach is right. I am bit lost in how to move forward with this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're grouping by Zone, you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), alongside [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const arr = [
  {Zone: "4", Org: 1},
  {Zone: "2", Org: 1},
  {Zone: "4", Mem: 32},
  {Zone: "2", Mem: 22}
]

const out = arr.reduce((a, o) => (a[o.Zone] = {...a[o.Zone], ...o}, a), {})
console.log(Object.values(out))
```

Note, this solution will add ALL other properties, and will overwrite them if they previously exist. Notice this will depend on ordering in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method:

```js
const arr =
    [{ Zone: "4", Org: 1 },
    { Zone: "2", Org: 1 },
    { Zone: "4", Mem: 32 },
    { Zone: "2", Mem: 22 }
    ];

const result = arr.reduce((a, {Zone, Org, Mem}) => {
    a[Zone] = a[Zone] || {Zone, Org};
    if (Mem)
        a[Zone].Mem = Mem;

    return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still learning how to use reduce method. I understood its use for adding up numbers. But always gets lost when it comes to modifying arrays in this way.